# linq with max() and join

Tags: linq

There is the linq statement I am using

```
            var renewalQuery = from r in crnnsupContext.Renewals
                               from w in crnnsupContext.WorkPlaces
                               join p in crnnsupContext.ProvStates on p.ProvinceStateID equals r.EmployerProvState
                               where  r.RegNumber == _username && r.PlaceOfWork == w.WorkID
                               select r;
```

There is a `r.RenewalYear` which I want to get the latest year, so I tried something like

```
                var renewalQuery = from r in crnnsupContext.Renewals
                               group r by r.RenewalYear into g
                               from w in crnnsupContext.WorkPlaces
                               join p in crnnsupContext.ProvStates on p.ProvinceStateID equals r.EmployerProvState
                               where  r.RegNumber == _username && r.PlaceOfWork == w.WorkID
                               select g.max(r.RenewalYear);
```

obviously it doesn't work, does anyone know the correct grammar for this? thanks very much

Comment: Are you looking to get only the latest RenewalYear that comes back to you, or is the latest year determined by the calendar year?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select your year and then use Max() on that:

```
var renewalQuery = (from r in crnnsupContext.Renewals
                               group r by r.RenewalYear into g
                               from w in crnnsupContext.WorkPlaces
                               join p in crnnsupContext.ProvStates on p.ProvinceStateID equals r.EmployerProvState
                               where  r.RegNumber == _username && r.PlaceOfWork == w.WorkID
                               select r.RenewalYear).Max();
```

Comment: there is an error "the name 'p' is not in scope on the left side of equals", besides is this only get the RenewalYear? i actually want to get the whole record with the latest RenewalYear

Comment: @pita, I thought your query was working and you just need the max year

Comment: @pita - it's not in scope on the left side, because it's the thing you are joining to and so it belongs to the right side: `from w in ...workPlaces join p in ...ProveStates on r.EmployerProvState equals p.ProvinceStateID`